# How to express something suits a group better?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

Once again, I'm stuck in a situation where I want to say a material is more suitable for a part of the society, a group of people, readers, and so forth; however, this time, I want to solve the problem, once and forever. I want to say this both in a formal context and in an informal one. Furthermore, I want to express this in two ways. Let's keep it simple; to be more specific, given the following sentences, how could I fill the blank?

> In this chapter we present a brief introduction to x, which ....

I'm dubious about these terms:

- is most suited for non-experts
- suits the non-experts better / the best.
- is aimed at non-experts.

> The ... of this chapter are non-experts.

- aim group! [all right, maybe this is completely wrong, but I think there is something like that.]

Comment: You might want to check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Target_audience. Its use is not limited to marketing. *Target readers* is also common.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Thanks, yes, seems that "target reader" fits the second sentence.

Comment: *is most suited for non-experts* sounds good to me. How about *recommended* or simply *suitable*? Also *be targeted*. 
You could use *beginners* or *laymen* to avoid the negation.

Comment: Layperson/laypeople?

Answer (score 1):

## 1:

> In this chapter we present a brief introduction to x, **for non-experts.**

No 'which' necessary.

## 2:

> The **target audience** of this chapter **is non-experts**.

At this point I'd like to mention that 'non-experts' is somewhat clunky, as is the rest of the sentence. I'd suggest rewriting this sentence as:

> **Beginners are** the **target audience** of this chapter.

You can replace 'beginners' with some other word representing your chosen group: 'amateurs' for a group that is minimally skilled (as opposed to 'professionals'), for example.

Comment: +1 for target audience. Indeed, I prefer not to change the style of the 1st sentence.